# paramId is null..Not retrieving oppId value from vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:column value="{!opp.id}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Import Records" action="{!CSVFile}">
                       <apex:param name="oppId" value="{!opp.id}" assignTo="
                       {!paramId}"/>  
</apex:commandButton>
```

---

```
  public String paramId{ get; set; }
  System.debug('paramIddddddd'+paramId ); 
  List<Opportunity> oppList = [Select Id from Opportunity where id=: paramId] ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `rerender` attribute of commandbutton to make it workable.

```
<apex:commandButton value="Import Records" action="{!CSVFile}" rerender="form">
      <apex:param name="oppId" value="{!opp.id}" assignTo="{!paramId}"/>  
</apex:commandButton>
```

Controller

```
public String paramId{ get; set; }
public void CSVFile()
{
    System.debug('paramIddddddd'+paramId ); 
    List<Opportunity> oppList = [Select Id from Opportunity where id=: paramId] ;
}
```